# Do I have to use signoutRedirectCallback in oidc-client.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

In my application for authentication I'm using IdentityServer + Angular with oidc-client.js.
When I want to logout from application then following code is run:

```
signout(): void {
  this.manager.signoutRedirect();
}
```

and to handle logout from other tabs

```
this.manager.events.addUserSignedOut(() => {
  this.manager.removeUser().then(() => {
    this.user = null;
    this.authNavStatusSource.next(false);
    this.router.navigate(["logout"]);
  });
});
```

Everything works fine, but I noticed that oidc-client provides also method `signoutRedirectCallback` which I don't have in my code.
[From documentation](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki):

> signoutRedirect: Returns promise to trigger a redirect of the current window to the end session endpoint.
>
> signoutRedirectCallback: Returns promise to process response from the end session endpoint.

Well it says nothing to me, still don't get it. What is this for? Do I really need this? In what case it might be useful?

Comment: Not always. As always, the answer is "it depends". [Here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/919) is a similar question to the IdentityServer developers and little bit of info.